# Allow http requests from front-end GKE app in GCloud Armor WAF

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, google-cloud-armor

I'm configuring a GCloud Armor to restrict access to my API which is deployed in GKE behind and ingress.
Some of the petitions come directly from de front-end which is also deployed in the GKE cluster and I need to allow those requests.
This front-end has currently 2 pods and I have tested that It works when I allow in GCloud Armor the external IPs of the nodes where those pods are deployed. Of course this is not a valid solution since the pods may change from nodes and the nodes are also volatile.

I have also an ingress for the front service which has a static IP, however allowing this IP in GCloud Armor doesn't work and still blocks the requests.

What's the best solution to solve this problem? Isn't there any option to set the front load balancer IP as the origin IP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your policy and Ingress config ?

Answer (score 0):

As workaround, you may create private GKE cluster https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters

and allow CloudNAT IP on CloudArmor.

Answer (score 0):

I solved It using tke kubernetes service as the endpoint for api calls from my front server.
It is not what I intended at start but is a workaround.